# Why html entities displayed wrong when I retrieved data from a web page in Java

Tags: java, html-entities

Why html entities displayed wrong when I retrieved data from a web page in Java:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.eslcafe.com/joblist/index.cgi?read=27334");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));

    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

The title of this page should be retrieved as " A LITTLE Different in Hsin-Chu, Taiwan!", but the " " never displayed correctly, my default charset is also "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: What's the actual source that gets printed?

Comment: I Just saw the [src of your site](http://www.eslcafe.com/joblist/index.cgi?read=27334). Even in the site there is no " " for the title.  ....<HTML><HEAD><TITLE> A LITTLE Different in Hsin-Chu, Taiwan!</TITLE>...... What is that you want?

Comment: <title>&nbsp;A LITTLE Different in Hsin-Chu, Taiwan!</title>

Comment: the html entity "&nbsp;" failed to display correctly, I just want to retrieve the page as it originally is

Comment: the result of the retrieved page is like this: <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>?A LITTLE Different in Hsin-Chu, Taiwan!</TITLE>, "&nbsp;" became a "?"

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded your Web page with curl and opened it with a hex editor. It shows that the " " before "A LITTLE Different in Hsin-Chu" is actually 0xA0 instead of 0x20, i.e. it's not the whitespace character people generally use, and perhaps that's why it's not displayed correctly. Hope it helps.

Comment: But in Google Chrome, when I view the page source, it is <title>&nbsp;A LITTLE Different in Hsin-Chu, Taiwan!</title>